# Render 2D blocky map - LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I have trouble to render a 2d blocky map.
Here how the 2d map array created :

```
map = new Block[w * h];
```

The block class contains 2 variables - size( H:100px, W:100px), and image texture.

Ok, so how should I render it?
I mean lets say the player is walking in the map, how should i make the map move / scroll effect.

I tried to loop through the map and render it but without any luck. because i need somehow to slice the block when i render it and i dont have any idea how to do that.
I really need help and it will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
map = new Block[w * h];
```

Should be a 2d array:

```
map = new Block[w][h];
```

Or I am misunderstanding?

- **Ok, so how should I render it?**
  If each block has an image texture then just loop through it, something like this:

  ```
  for(int i=0; i<w; i++){
      for(int j=0; j<h; j++){
          Block b = map[i][j];
          spritebatcher.draw(b.texture, i*b.W, j*b.H);
      }
  }
  ```
- **how should i make the map move / scroll effect?**
  Technically the map won't scroll. You move your player and the camera will follow him/her.

  ```
  camera.position.set(player.position.x, player.position.y, 0);
  ```
- **i need somehow to slice the block when i render it and i dont have any idea how to do that.**
  I'm afraid I don't understand this particular issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. but wait i didnt know you have camera thing in libGDX.. let me check that out. thanks anyways buddy!

Comment: And about the arrays.. i did 1D array for the sake of performance. it works like this `map[y *width + x]`.

Comment: 1D arrays offer slim to no gain in performance, and just usually cause headaches. However, its fine to use them if you want!